# Función replace() para reemplazar varias letras

Tags: javascript, funciones, regex

Quiero optimizar esta función en la cual le paso una frase y cambio algunas letras por otras

```
const foo = (frase = "El teclado qWerTy") => {
  
  frase = frase
    .replace(/q/g, "1")
    .replace(/w/g, "2")
    .replace(/e/g, "3")
    .replace(/r/g, "4")
    .replace(/t/g, "5");
    .replace(/y/g, "6");

  console.log(frase);

};
```

Existe alguna forma de hacerlo en un único replace?

Se que se puede hacer algo así para agrupar con regex, pero esto solo serviría para un único caracter

```
'Las Vocales Cambian'.replace(/[aeiou]/ig,'x');
```

*Output // Lxs Vxcxlxs Cxmbxxn*

Alguien tendría una idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extrapolando lo que he visto [en esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15604206/10382744) del SO en ingles, podrias hacer lo siguiente en tu caso concreto:

```js
var str = "El teclado qWerTy.";
var mapObj = {
   q:"1",
   w:"2",
   e:"3",
   r:"4",
   t:"5",
   y:"6"

};
str = str.replace(/q|w|e|r|t|y/g, function(matched){
  return mapObj[matched];
});

console.log(str)
```

Con esta solución, lo que hacemos en pasarle una función al [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#sintaxis) en lugar de una cadena (string), y en dicha función se ejecuta el `return` del valor de la propiedad coincidente del objeto `mapObj` (que encerramos mediante la [notación de corchetes](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#notaci.c3.b3n_por_corchetes) para su correcta interpretación durante su ejecución) por cada una de las coincidencias de la expresión regular.

Tal como dice [su documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#resumen):

> El patrón puede ser una cadena o una RegExp, y el reemplazo puede ser
> una cadena o una función que será llamada para cada coincidencia.

En ese objeto `mapObj` lo que hacemos es definir como propiedades las coincidencias a modificar, y como valores de esas propiedades los strings que usaremos como reemplazos.

Con esta solución usarias un solo `replace`, y tu código quedaría un poco más ordenado, aunque no veo que sea demasiado menos extenso que el anterior, pero quizás ya te sirva. Ya nos dirás.

Comment: Es cierto que quizás no es mucho menos extenso, e igual es incluso más confuso de leer, pero entiendo, que haciéndolo de esta forma, en tiempo de ejecución mejorará ya que no tiene que leer la cadena entera por cada uno de los replace e ir comparando cada caracter por cada letra por la cual se quiera cambiar, muchas gracias!